# MIKTEX - The XCharter-Roman-tlf-sc-t1--base source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex

I am trying to build a CV with pdflatex (MikTeX) but it fails. The error is as follows:

```
Trying to make PK font XCharter-Roman-tlf-sc-t1--base at 720 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The XCharter-Roman-tlf-sc-t1--base source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk

: PK font XCharter-Roman-tlf-sc-t1--base could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)
```

**NOTE:** I checked the available config files (updmap.cfg) files for the Map XCharter-Roman-tlf-sc-t1--base.map entry. I found the entry in the file MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg.

What else can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Run updmap on the command line.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer! Done. But it is of no use...

Comment: Run `updmap --verbose > updmap.log` and show the log-file it creates.

Comment: Yes, I run "updmap --verbose > updmap.log", and generate a log-file. But, I am unable to find, where is it? I am using windows and miktex 2.9 user. Help

Comment: The command prompt should tell you where you are, when you call updmap. E.g `C:\test>` means that you are in C:\test.

Comment: Thank You. @Ulrike Fischer.. This is the  last two lines of the log file.                                                                                                   C:/Users/SIBA/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fontconfig/cache: cleaning cache directory                                                                            C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\fc-cache.EXE: succeeded

Comment: Why do you think that the two last lines matter? You have a problem with xcharter, so check if the map is used.

Comment: Okay.. I am checking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39331/discussion-between-siba-mishra-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: It works.. Thank you @UlrikeFischer for your help... The suggestion is as follows:  Add the following in \updmap.cfg
# xcharter
Map XCharter.map
And then run updmap again.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and the above comment solves the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.