# File XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1 not found

Tags: fonts, errors, texlive

(update)

Reverted xcharter back to version 1.08 (from 1.09) via tlmgr, and now it's working again. So I suspect it's a problem of the new version.

Also, to add a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{article}
\usepackage{XCharter} 
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

The document compiles with xcharter 1.08, but fails with error quoted below if xcharter is updated to 1.09

Also contacted the package maintainer by email just now.

---

Posted a [question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376878/what-math-font-is-a-good-complement-for-charter-font) yesterday which math font to use with XCharter, and started using:

```
\usepackage[scale=0.97,osf]{XCharter} % >> 0.97 (0.96)
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb,scaled=1.05]{newtxmath}
\let\openbox\undefined
```

I upgraded TeX Live today, and the same code isn't running anymore, with the error message:

```
Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "0-root".tex

kpathsea: Running mktextfm XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1

/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation X for XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1. /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1

This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1

! I can't find file `XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1'. <*> ... nonstopmode; input XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ... nonstopmode; input XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1 Transcript written on mfput.log.
```

The relevant part seems to be the missing file `XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1`.

I already saw the (possibly) [related question on here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307684/miktex-the-xcharter-roman-tlf-sc-t1-base-source-file-could-not-be-found-runn), and ran both `updmap -sys` and `updmap -user`, and checked whether `XCharter.map` is in `updmap.cfg`, which it is.

Any log info I can provide to track down the problem?

Comment: There is no file `XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1` on my system, only `XCharter-Roman-tlf-ot1`. I think this is normal, as the difference between `XCharter` and `XCharter1` is about the style of `1`in `osf`, and `XCharter1-Roman-tlf-ot1` would have  lining figures.

Comment: @Bernard Makes sense. I did a `find` over the entire system, and I don't have the file either. Still, compilation fails with the report that the file is missing. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: It's easier to know with a minimal full code reproducing the problem…

Comment: Just reverted back to xcharter 1.08 and the problem disappeared, so I guess it's related to the new 1.09 version. Will update my question accordingly, and include a MWE

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to post some code that we can play with.

Comment: Do NOT run `updmap --user`. Once you do this once, no update to TeX Live will be reflected in any changes to the font information for the current user (until we get TeX Live 2018 or you undo the damage done).

Comment: Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i. There are instructions at the bottom of my answer which tell you how to undo the damage.

Comment: @Bernard Eek. Look what the new version does to `\textsc`! That's really nasty.

Comment: @cfr: I'm anxious to see that, but I'll have to wait – it wasn't updated in MiKTeX yet, and I don't think it's worth installing it by hand to be the first MiKTeX user to have the new version! ;o)

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the pointer. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @Bernard I don't have it either. I just looked on CTAN. (I don't know whether I would get it if I updated, but I'm not really keen right now!)